# Pysandbox configuration questions

Tags: python, configuration, eval, sandbox

I have two questions regarding Pysandbox:

1. How do I achieve the functionality of `eval`? I understand `sandbox.execute()` is equivalent to `exec`, but I can't find anything such that if the code entered were `2 + 2`, then it would return `4`, or something to that effect.
2. By default, `sandbox.execute()` makes a passed-in environment read-only -- i.e. if I do `sandbox.execute('data.append(4)', locals={'data': [1, 2, 3]})`, an error will occur. How do I make passed-in environments read-write?

Comment: Are we looking at the same Pysandbox- the one at https://github.com/haypo/pysandbox ? Your second example seems to work without errors for me, and the first looks like it's asking for sandbox.call(lambda: 2+2).

Comment: Yes, that is the same module. The second example threw an error about the object being read-only. As far as eval, I want a function that automatically attempts eval such that I won't need to parse the input to determine whether it is code that warrants eval vs. exec

Comment: Perhaps there is a difference in the way you set up your sandbox. Could you post an entire script and the error you get when trying to update?

Comment: Essentially all I do is create a sandbox instance named `s`, and perform the exact line specified in 2. I then get the exception `sandbox.SandboxError: Read only object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, I see that the last PySandbox release (1.5) does behave as you describe. I was trying on the git master branch.

For question 1, I don't think there are any straightforward options with PySandbox 1.5. The code has been written specifically to try and disallow modification or transmission of any state while inside the sandbox. `sandbox.call(eval, CODE)` is not a good option, since you can't very easily pass in the locals and globals namespaces (you can try, but the sandbox will proxy them, and then eval() will fail because locals and globals have to be real dicts). And I believe you want to be able to set the locals and globals here.

Question 2 isn't straightforward either, for similar reasons. Both of these are possible on the current git master branch, but it's not obvious whether that's because of bugs or by design :)

So here's a solution to both questions which sort of extends the sandbox functionality and uses what is probably meant to be a private interface, but should still be as safe as the sandbox is otherwise:

```
from sandbox.proxy import proxy
from sandbox.sandbox_class import _call_exec

def proxyNamespace(d):
    return dict((str(k), proxy(v)) for k, v in d.iteritems())

def wrapeval(codestr, globs, locs):
    subglobs = proxyNamespace(globs)
    sublocs = proxyNamespace(locs)
    return eval(codestr, subglobs, sublocs)

def eval_in_sandbox(sandbox, codestr, globs=None, locs=None):
    if globs is None:
        globs = {}
    if locs is None:
        locs = globs
    return sandbox._call(wrapeval, (codestr, locs, globs), {})

def exec_in_sandbox_with_mutable_namespace(sandbox, codestr, globs=None, locs=None):
    if globs is None:
        globs = {}
    if locs is None:
        locs = globs
    subglobs = proxyNamespace(globs)
    sublocs = proxyNamespace(locs)
    sandbox._call(_call_exec, (codestr, subglobs, sublocs), {})
    globs.update(subglobs)
    locs.update(sublocs)
```

Now, all that said, I strongly recommend *not* basing the safety of any actual production code or system on this PySandbox module. In looking through the code, it seems like it's completely riddled with flaws and holes. I don't think it would take an attacker longer than an hour or so to find ways past this sort of security. I also don't think this has undergone any serious review by security professionals, or even a very big part of the community at large. If you want to run untrusted code and have it not be able to affect your process at all, you need something lots stronger, probably based around AppArmor or something like that. If you are only worried about accidentally misbehaving code, as opposed to malicious, this might be ok, but I'm actually not even sure about that.

Comment: I admit that PySandbox may not a serurity way. But your way is much misleading.

Comment: Sandbox._call will not be used to execute any code unless you like to be the "Victim". I shall only call sandbox.execute to run any untrusted code. Can you give a example?

Comment: @wuliang I'm not sure what you mean. What is misleading? And what do you want an example of?

Comment: pau , I agree that your method is suitable for the question. But if you say PySandbox is not serurity enough, you should give a example using "sandbox.execute(...)" not "sandbox._call(...)", since its the correct API for the user of  PySandbox.

Comment: @wuliang the security flaws in pysandbox are the same, whether one uses these `eval_in_sandbox()`/`exec_in_sandbox_with_mutable_namespace()` functions or the `Sandbox.execute()` method. That is to say, my functions are as secure as `execute()`, if the user understands that the untrusted code is allowed to modify the passed-in keyspaces. It's just that `execute()` (and the framework as a whole) is not that secure.

Comment: (1). Only execute() and call() are given in example in https://github.com/haypo/pysandbox (2). _call() is obviously a non-public API in python-convention, http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private (3)Your logic (and the code snippet) is just like "a rootkit in *NIX". Can it prove anything?

Comment: Yes, _call is not a public API. I acknowledged that. That does not mean it's insecure. Look at the code for call() and execute() and you can see how my code is essentially the same thing, with the one change that the passed-in namespaces are not themselves proxied.  I have no idea why you think this is like a rootkit. This would be set up by the owner of the sandbox, not by untrusted code inside it. So it is more analogous to a *nix sysadmin giving special extra permissions to a user account via sudo, and nothing like a rootkit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11125/discussion-between-wuliang-and-the-paul)

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:

```
sandbox.call(eval, "2+2")
```

Question 2:

```
from sandbox import Sandbox, SandboxConfig
cfg=SandboxConfig('stdout')
import sys

out1 = sys.stdout
err1 = sys.stderr
with open("logfile.txt", "w") as f:    
    sys.stdout = sys.stderr = f
    sandbox = Sandbox(cfg)
    indata={'data': [1, 2, 3]}
    sandbox.execute('a=list(data);a.append(4); print(str(a))', locals=indata)

sys.stdout = out1
sys.stderr = err1

with open("logfile.txt", "r") as f: 
    indata=eval(f.read())
    print indata
```

Some remark about the question 2, It's hard to get a Readable-Writebale object and make it seen from outside at same time. I'd like to see some smarter methods.

**OUTPUT:**

```
$ python test.py 
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: It would be pretty much useless to run code in a sandbox and then go ahead and eval() whatever the sandboxed code printed to stdout.

Comment: Unfortunately, I would still like to write changes to the environment for 1) as well. For 2), I'm not sure how this method would work for objects more complex then basic data structures and literals. Namely, if I made a function that I wanted to store in the environment, I'm not quite sure how I would do that using this method.

Comment: @Zach, I think there is no common way to do that. What "sandbox" do is to make your code running in its virtual box. Even we can find some trick to get it work, it is a hacker method and will be disabled when "sandbox" upgrated to patch hole.